# export null values to xml from a dataset

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

If you have a null value in a field in a dataset and export it to xml it does "remove" the field tag .. anyway to avoid this..

Answer (score 1):

An empty tag does not have the same meaning as `null`, especially for strings. How would you make the difference if the tag was present but empty?

Comment: null or empty is the same for in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try changing values of cells.

foreach (DataRow row in dtPr.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtPr.Columns.Count; i++)
    {


    dtPr.Columns[i].ReadOnly = false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[i].ToString()))
        {
            if (dtPr.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(string))
                row[i] = string.Empty;
            else if (dtPr.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(int))
                row[i] = 0;
            else if (dtPr.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                row[i] = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of NULL as a state and everything else as a value.  So if you want a blank value, just send in an empty string (single white space)

Answer (score -1):

you have to paint your method with an attribute that tells it to stay there.  not near my winblows machine so cant give you the actual code. but would look something like this,

```
[XMLElement(IsNullable = true)]
myProperty {get;set;}
```

Comment: -1: Note he's talking about a DataSet, so there's no property to put the attribute on.